# Three.js - dealing with a large number of instances

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been using three.js for a scene with a large number of 200-300 vertices instances (~2000). Right now I introduces some postprocessing effects with the EffectComposer and noticed some slowdowns.

Is there any way to deal with slowness caused by a large number of instances (which are not visible at the same time in the scene at all times)?

I've been creating my instances with

`var newObject = object.clone();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some OpenGL Instancing tutorials:

https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing

Also Three.js instancing example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html

Basically the idea is that the data of the instances can be shared. It can't be shared if you simply use `object.clone()`.